# Tkinter- Open and Save the UI with all the widgets. Trouble while incrementing the rows

Tags: python, tkinter

Here, is the piece of code that I have written. I have to make Open and Save Button functional. So, my both functions are working fine. I am able to Save and Load UI but the basic problem is that after loading, when I click on ***add rows***, the rows doesn't added in below the already existed row. It has been a week working on it. I am in trouble and doesnt know the wayout

```
from tkinter import *
import dill
from collections import OrderedDict
class Program: 
    def __init__(self):
        self.row=0
        self.entries=[]
        self.current_widget=0
        self.Ordered_dictionary_for_entry_widget=OrderedDict() 
        self.values_for_entry_dictionary=[]
        self.AddButton = Button(text="Add Row", command=self.add_button_command)
        self.AddButton.grid(column=0,row=0)
        self.save_button=Button(text="save",command=self.save_button_command)
        self.save_button.grid(column=0,row=1)
        self.load_button=Button(text="Open",command=self.Open_button_command)
        self.load_button.grid(column=0,row=2)
        self.total_entries_length=len(self.entries)
    def add_button_command(self):
        self.entry=Entry()
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=self.row)
        self.entries.append(self.entry)
        self.row=self.row+1
    def save_button_command(self):
        self.total_entries_length=len(self.entries)
        print(self.total_entries_length)
        for widget in self.entries:
           self.Ordered_dictionary_for_entry_widget["Name"+str(self.current_widget+1)]=widget.get()
           self.current_widget=self.current_widget+1
        with open("example_fully_functional.txt","wb") as f:
            dill.dump(self.Ordered_dictionary_for_entry_widget,f)
    def Open_button_command(self):
        print("Total entries length",self.total_entries_length)
        with open("example_fully_functional.txt","rb") as f:
            self.Ordered_dictionary_for_entry_widget=dill.load(f)
            for key,values in self.Ordered_dictionary_for_entry_widget.items():
            self.values_for_entry_dictionary.append((values))  
            print(self.values_for_entry_dictionary)
        for i in (self.values_for_entry_dictionary):
            self.entry=Entry()
            self.entry.grid(column=1,row=i)
            self.entries.append(self.entry)
            print("Entry loaded",self.entries_loaded)
            #Insert the entries back into the UI
        [self.entries.insert(0,self.values_for_entry_dictionary) for
        self.entries,self.values_for_entry_dictionary in
        zip(self.entries,self.values_for_entry_dictionary)]

program = Program()

mainloop()
```

Comment: There are many places where you use row=something_other_than_self.row.  Use self.row in all cases.  There is no way to tell from your code where you want the add_button_command function to add the next row, so there is little more that can be done to assist you.  Finally, you have no Tk() instance so this program will not run from the terminal, and may or may not run from something like Idle that has already created a Tk() instance.

Comment: This is actually a miniature of what I have programmed. Open button: actually opens the already saved UI but after clicking the open button, if I click on add rows then it should start adding rows below the already open rows but it is not doing so.

Comment: Some of the indentation seems off. For example there's a `for` loop in `Open_button_command` that doesn't have an indented body. We can't help if we can't tell exactly how the code is written. You should also consider replacing the last list comprehension with a simple loop. It's hard to read and hard to debug since you can't step through it and look at what each iteration is doing.

Comment: @BryanOakley i am new to this field. My code is not accurate. Do you some otherway to save multiple widgets in a UI and then open it again. After opening, you can still edit it. Like add more widgets to it

Comment: @BryanOakley Basically I have to make an editor that can save the UI in some xyz format and  open the already saved UI. Is there any way out for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok to answer the direct question: `self.row` is not incremented in `Open_button_command` so it is inaccurate when `add_button_command` tries to add a new `Entry`,

```
    for i in (self.values_for_entry_dictionary):
        self.entry=Entry()
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=i)
        self.entries.append(self.entry)
        ## THIS ONE HERE ##
        self.row+=1
        #####
```

I want to suggest a better solution then keeping track of the next column in a variable but before I can we need to fix up a few things, first in `Open_button_command`:

```
    for i in (self.values_for_entry_dictionary):
        self.entry=Entry()
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=i)
        ...
```

You are iterating over the values that need to be inserted into the entries not the indices, to get the indices to use in `.grid` you can use `range(len(X))` instead:

```
 for i in range(len(self.values_for_entry_dictionary)):
```

or better yet use `enumerate` to make the Entries and fill them at the same time:

```
 for i,value in enumerate(self.values_for_entry_dictionary):
        self.entry=Entry()
        self.entry.grid(column=1,row=i)
        self.entry.insert(0,value)
        ...
```

this way you don't need this:

```
    [self.entries.insert(0,self.values_for_entry_dictionary) for
    self.entries,self.values_for_entry_dictionary in
    zip(self.entries,self.values_for_entry_dictionary)]
```

which overrides `self.entries` and `self. self.values_for_entry_dictionary` during the loop so a lot of information gets messed up during that, use `enumerate` instead.

Once that is cleaned up and `self.entries` will consistently be a list of all the `Entry` widgets in window the `self.row` should always be equal to `len(self.entries)` so it would be much preferable to use a [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#property) to calculate it every time:

```
class Program:
    @property
    def row(self):
        return len(self.entries)
    ...
```

Then comment out any statement trying to set `self.row=X` since you don't have or need a `setter` for it. Every time you use `self.row` it will calculate it with the property and `add_button_command` will always add a new entry to the bottom.

However in `Open_button_command` you are still creating new widgets even if there is already an `Entry` in the window, it would make more sense to check if there is already one that can be reused:

```
def Open_button_command(self):
    ...
    for i,value in enumerate(self.values_for_entry_dictionary):
        if i<len(self.entries):
            self.entry = self.entries[i]
            self.entry.delete(0,"end") #remove any previous content
        else:
            self.entry=Entry()
            self.entry.grid(column=1,row=i)
            self.entries.append(self.entry)
        # either way:
        self.entry.insert(0,value)
```

Although this still breaks if you hit the open button twice since you do not reset `self.values_for_entry_dictionary` when opening a file, so the values in the file are added to any already open Entries so it would be a good idea to also reset it when opening a file:

```
def Open_button_command(self):
    self.values_for_entry_dictionary=[]
    ...
```

If you wanted help with a working but buggy code you might [consider submitting it for review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) and I'd be happy to provide other tips but I think this is sufficient to at least get the example code working as expected.